# getValues() Google Sheets App Script not working - Returns a single array

Tags: javascript

My Code: getValues() for some reason works and afterwards fails to work on other days. It seems "response" is only getting an array(8) of 1 column? I am grabbing a array of values but it only returns 1st column
`enter code here`

```
    if (response == 1) { var response = 'B5:E12'}
  if (response == 2) { var response = 'B13:E20'}
  if (response == 3) { var response = 'B21:E28'}
  if (response == 4) { var response = 'B29:E34'}
  if (response == 5) { var response = 'B37:E45'}
  if (response == 6) { var response = 'B46:E53'}
  if (response == 7) { var response = 'B54:E61'}
  if (response == 8) { var response = 'B62:E69'}
  if (response == 9) { var response = 'B70:E77'}
  if (response == 10) { var response = 'B78:E85'}
  if (response == 11) { var response = 'B86:E93'}
  if (response == 12) { var response = 'B94:E101'}
    
  response = response.toString();

  // Gather Data to prep Table and Email (to: and cc:)

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheetr = sheet.getSheetByName('Reporting');
  var sheeta = sheet.getSheetByName('Assignments');
  var data = sheetr.getRange(response).getValues();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, I can confirm alternating results on different days and even the same day minutes apart on my own functions with the same input. It's made of stuff to induce insanity while debugging.

I also noted something recently...

`var Horz = s.getRange(r,c, 3,1).getValues();`
returns a 1D array of 3 indexes each with a value

`var Vert = s.getRange(r,c, 1,3).getValues();`
returns a 2D array of 1 index with all 3 values